# Force Yii2 FileHelper to use forward slash

Tags: php, yii2

```
$dir = "assets/slides";
$files = FileHelper::findFiles($dir, ['only' => ['*.jpg']]);

foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<img src="' . $file . '" alt="" />';
}
```

It produce the output:

```
<img src="assets/slides\img-1.jpg" alt="">
```

It cause HTML validation error due to backward slash (slides\img-1.jpg).
I want to generate URL like-

```
<img src="assets/slides/img-1.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you need url and not the path  (and because you path is windows that use a different slash respect the url)
then try replace

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);
    echo '<img src="' . $file . '" alt="" />';
}
```

Comment: Can I just get file name i.e. img-1.jpg instead of \img-1.jpg, in FileHelper

Comment: You can take a look at the ref ..In http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-filehelper.html . there isn't a flag for remove the slash from the filename... eventually you can use function ...for  look at the options  in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles()-detail